# What is the best way to convert word file into tex?

Tags: conversion, msword, word-to-latex

I have many word files containing equations (they are completely prepared in word ). Is there an effective way to convert these into tex files?

Comment: If you fine as commercial, then try with `Chikri` and `GrindEq`, and if you search for free tool, then try with https://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/